# vscode with a local .git repository saying "too many active changes"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My project used to be developed by PhCharm, and was version-controlled locally with its built-in git function. Just lately it is shifted to VSCode, but every time loading the project, it says "The git repository at 'XXXX' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled." If I modified a file, it doesn't even show up in the "Source Control" pane. It basically means I cannot use the built-in git now in VSCode. What can I do to use the VSCode's git functions with my project?

Thanks!

Comment: You are most likely not  `.gitignore`ing things like `node_modules` or any other third-party dependencies you shouldn't be versioning.

Comment: This is due to lots of untracked files in your local. This may be included your configurations file. Add them in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many untracked files and git stops working at its full capability.
To fix the issue, you need to create a `.gitignore` file that fits your needs and helps you to not track file generated by automation tools, packaging systems, etc...

If you need more information on how to create a `.gitignore`, you can try to do some research, there's plenty of useful docs.

I suggest you to take a look at the `.gitignore` files provided by Github.
You can find them here: https://github.com/github/gitignore
If you are using Python, you may found useful this one: [python.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)
Basically, search the file that best fit the language you are using and copy it in a file named `.gitignore` in the root of your project.